# How do i get update to stop running when I click?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Here is a code segment where i am  trying to make update stop running so that I can put a dot on the canvas. When I try to get `putPoint` to return `clicked = true`, it makes clicked equal true regardless if I click or not. I just want to return true if and only if I click.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
//canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var radius = 2;
var dragging = false; // wether or not the mouse button is held down
ctx.lineWidth = radius * 2;
var canvasPos = getPosition(canvas);
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;
var clicked = false;
// here is where I declare clicked = true globally

function update() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(mouseX, mouseY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
  ctx.fill();

  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", setMousePosition, false);

function setMousePosition(e) {
  mouseX = e.clientX;
  mouseY = e.clientY;
}

//console.log("before update " + clicked);

if (clicked != true) {
  update();
  //console.log("inside update " +clicked);
}
// here is the code I want to stop when I click

//console.log("after update " + clicked);

function putPoint() {
  //e.clientX and e.clientY get the mouse position
  ctx.beginPath();
  //e.clientX and e.clientY get the mouse position
  ctx.arc(mouseX - 10, mouseY - 10, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  //ctx.arc(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fill();
  //console.log("inside putPoint " + clicked);
}

//putPoint puts a dot on the canvas at the mouse position. But it wont fire unless
//I stop update, which tracks my dot.

//console.log("after putPoint " + clicked);


canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", putPoint);
//console.log(putPoint());

//console.log(clicked);

function getPosition(el) {
  var xPosition = 0;
  var yPosition = 0;

  while (el) {
    xPosition += (el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft + el.clientLeft);
    yPosition += (el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop + el.clientTop);
    el = el.offsetParent;
  }
  return {
    x: xPosition,
    y: yPosition
  };
}
```

```html
<canvas id=myCanvas>
</canvas>
```

---

below is a smaller reproduction of the problem. basically I am trying to update my variable to true when i click on the element. But when I return true or even set clicked to to true within the test function, it still reads true wether I click or not. It doesnt dynamically change. Maybe Im using the wrong event ? im not sure.

```
var clicked = false;

console.log(clicked);
function test () {
    return true;
}

clicked = test();

console.log(clicked);

document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].addEventListener("mousedown", test);
```

Comment: I said clicked = true I meant that I set it to false globally

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Comment: thanks for editing my post. I didnt even know you can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm inferring a bit based on clues from both the used and unused (e.g. dragging variable) parts of your first snippet, but it seems to me like you are trying to draw a point that tracks with your mouse, and then once a click event has occurred you want to start drawing points dragging after the mouse until that click is released.

### First, your issue with your 'clicked' tracking

I think you are misunderstanding when different statements are executed. In your second snippet all of the statements outside of the 'test' event handler function are only executed once.  The 'test' function will be called with each mouse click, but simply returns true and does not change the value of 'clicked'. So, the statement:

```
var clicked = false;
```

...and the statement:

```
clicked = test();
```

...each only execute once.  Here is a quick example to show you how you could track the toggling of that value. Try a simple click and also holding the click for a second before releasing to get the idea.

```js
  var clicked = false;
  var clickableArea = document.getElementById("clickable");
  clickableArea.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    clicked = true;
    console.log('Clicked, value of clicked var: ' + clicked);
  });

  clickableArea.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    clicked = false;
    console.log('Released, value of clicked var: ' + clicked);
  });
```

```html
<div id="clickable">Click Me</div>
```

### What I think you are going for with your canvas rendering:

Move the mouse around and then click and drag the mouse.

```js
  var canvas, ctx;
  var radius = 2;
  var mouseX = 0;
  var mouseY = 0;
  var clicked = false;
  var dragging = false;


  // manages the drawing cycle
  function putPoint() {

    // clear the canvas if not dragging, or just before the first draw of a dragging cycle
    if(!dragging) {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }

    dragging = clicked;

    // draw
    var offset = dragging ? 10 : 0;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(mouseX-offset, mouseY-offset, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    ctx.fill();

    // kick off another cycle
    requestAnimationFrame(putPoint);
  }


  // event handlers

  function trackMouse(e) {
    mouseX = e.clientX;
    mouseY = e.clientY;
  }

  function startedDragging() {
    clicked = true;
  }

  function quitDragging() {
    clicked = false;
    dragging = false;
  }


  // only runs once when called below, sets things up, starts the drawing cycle
  function start() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.lineWidth = radius * 2;

    // attach events to handlers
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", trackMouse, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startedDragging);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", quitDragging);

    requestAnimationFrame(putPoint);
  }

  start(); // calling start to kick things off
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas">
</canvas>
```

Comment: This definitely works. Thanks there was a lot of effort here and I learned a lot.